# Filament Import fopen error in Digital Ocean

Tags: php, laravel-excel, laravel-filament

Hello everything is fine?
I have a problem using Filament Import with Digital Ocean Spaces. In my system, I have PDFs, XMLs and images, which upload works normally and I can send them to this storage. The problem is the CSV spreadsheets that I send via Filament Import. The spreadsheet loads (shows 100%), and there in Digital Ocean I can see it in the livewire-tmp folder. However, an error occurs and the following message is displayed:

```
ErrorException
PHP 8.1.17
10.35.0
fopen(app_files\livewire-tmp/XV08fzdkZ2mgHPqyCg71IBTD4dv947-metaUGVkaWRvcy5jc3Y=-.csv): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Here the file in Digital Ocean Spaces:
[CSV Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEaOv.png)

Could anyone help me with this? I thought it was a configuration thing, but I can send any files using SpatieMediaLibrary. The only problem occurs when using Filament Import. Everything works normally on my localhost

Step by step of what I tried:

1. Click on the button to import the CSV file
2. I selected the file
3. It loaded and showed 100%
4. A Laravel exception message occurs with the error:
   fopen(app_files\livewire-tmp/XV08fzdkZ2mgHPqyCg71IBTD4dv947-metaUGVkaWRvcy5jc3Y=-.csv): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What I expected:
The file was loaded, and its columns were displayed normally